# jquery animation and .offset

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have an image that is 780px long and I have a window through which you can only see 390px at a time. There are left and right arrows so you can scroll one way and then the other. I would like the arrows to be disabled once you reach the end of the image either at 0px or -780px. I have tried the following code just to see if I am going in the right direction however it **only** works with the ">" sign and I need it to work with "==":

```
$(function() {

    $(".big-fwd img").click(function() {
        var offset = $(".wrap-nga").offset();


        $(".wrap-nga").animate({
            left: "-=390px"
        })
        if (offset > "-780px") {
            alert("hello");
        }
    });
```

The second problem is that when I write the code I really want to have instead of the alert, nothing at all happens:

```
$(function() {

    $(".big-fwd img").click(function() {
        var offset = $(".wrap-nga").offset();


        $(".wrap-nga").animate({
            left: "-=390px"
        })
        if (offset > "-780px") {
            $(".big-fwd img").removeAttr();
        }
    });
```

I'm really at a loss. I've tried "position" instead of "offset" but that's not the problem. 
Any help would be fantastic. You can also get a better idea of what I'm trying to do by going to http://www.lieslswogger.com and clicking on one of the images in the gallery. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

I think your comparison issue is due to the fact the the result of $.offset() is an object, not a value.

From http://api.jquery.com/offset/

> .offset() returns an object containing the properties top and left.

You probably want to use offset.left, in your case.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Do the offset check before animating. You also will need to compare a numeric value for the inequalities in this case.

```
$(".big-fwd img").click(function(){  
    var offset = $(".wrap-nga").offset();
    if(offset.left < 780)
        $(".wrap-nga").animate({ left: "-=390px" })
});
```

Similarly on back `.big-back img`:

```
if(offset.left > 0) // proceed with animation
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help - sorry I didn't respond earlier, got sidetracked with another project. Doing the offset check before animating worked perfectly for moving the images forward (."big-fwd img") but for some reason isn't working for (."big-back img"). The image continues to scroll past 0. Anyone have any ideas as to why this might be? Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: just check the left property, perhaps `0` is not the right value.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you close your function. It should be:

```
$(function() {    
    $(".big-fwd img").click(function() {
        var offset = $(".wrap-nga").offset();

        $(".wrap-nga").animate({
            left: "-=390px"
        }) if (offset > "-780px") {
            $(".big-fwd img").removeAttr();
        }
    });
});
```